# com_error workbooks.Add()

Tags: python, jenkins, win32com

```
import time
from win32com import client
from win32com.client import constants as c
import os

wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
ws.Name = "mysheet"
```

This is first few lines of my script. when i run the script it throws following exception

```
C:\Executables>Planning.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Executables\Planning.py", line 26, in <module>
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
File "C:\python272\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x6\Workbooks.py", line 34, in Add
ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(181, LCID, 1, (13, 0), ((12, 17),),Template
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Office Excel', u'Microsoft Office Excel kann keine weiteren Dateien \xf6ffnen oder speichern, da nicht gen\xfcgend Arbeitsspeicher oder Festplattenspeicherplatz vorhanden ist.\n\n\u2022 Schlie\xdfen Sie andere Arbeitsmappen oder Programme, die Sie nicht mehr ben\xf6tigen, um mehr Speicherplatz verf\xfcgbar zu machen.\n\n\u2022 L\xf6schen Sie nicht mehr ben\xf6tigte Dateien vom Datentr\xe4ger, um mehr Speicherplatz verf\xfcgbar zu machen.', u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\1031\\XLMAIN11.CHM', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Sorry the error is in German. The problem is it works fine in my machine but when i run it via `jenkins` on a server it throws this error. But when i tried to create a new workbook using `xlwt` it is working fine. can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Code that uses Excel COM will only work on a machine that has MS Office installed. The xlwt does not use Excel's COM API so that one works on both the desktop and server.